Error: "This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context."
I get an error when I try to send data through a http request using Dio.
This is the code:
  void register() async {
    // show loading screen
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );

    // try create the user
    try {
      UserCredential? userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text, password: _passwordController.text);

      Navigator.pop(context);

      // create user document and send it to api
      createUserData(userCredential.user!.uid);

      // pop loading circle
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      // pop loading circle
      //Navigator.pop(context);

      // display error message to user
      displayNotification(context, e.code);
    }
  }

  void createUserData(String uid) async {
    try {
      var data = {
        "userId": uid,
        "clientName": _firstNameController.text.toString(),
        "email": _emailController.text.toString(),
      };

      Response response =
          await Dio().post(createAccountEndpoint, data: jsonEncode(data));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // display error message
        displayNotification(context, "Your account was created successfully!");
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginOrRegister()),
        );
      } else {
        displayNotification(context, "Error!");
      }
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      print("Create Account ERROR ->  ${e.message}");
    }
  }

I got the following error when I enter in "createUserData(userCredential.user!.uid);":

This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct. Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active

I've tried to comment that line and it works, but does not send the request.
I've tried to use Navigator.pop() and remove all of them, but still not working.

What happens if you use await createUserData... and call Navigator.pop(context); after this line?

@PeterKoltai it shows the same error

It seems you need pass context from where you call register function and pass it to. createUserData func
like this
void register(BuildContext context) async {
    // show loading screen
     createUserData(context);
   }

 void createUserData(BuildContext context, String uid) async {
  ...
  ...
   }


Well, that gives me another error
"Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable"

share the whole dart file where this happen to make this clear !
@André

Alright! There it go https://pastebin.com/y9qVKUB7 . I also tried the code that Waseem Abbas provided, but still not working tho

Try this hope this may  fix the issue  https://pastecode.io/s/0spmoqfr

Well, it's giving me an error when passing the context to the function in the "onTap"

"his expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
Try checking to see if you're using the correct API; there might be a function or call that returns void you didn't expect. Also check type parameters and variables which might also be void"

try remove void from register function https://pastecode.io/s/vbvr6no5

Now I'm getting another one when launching the register page
"FlutterError (setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase."

Try the following solution:
void register() async {
    // show loading screen
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );

    // try create the user
    final result = await createUser();
  
  
    displayNotification(context, result.values.first);
  
    Navigator.pop(context);
  
    if(result.keys.first) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginOrRegister()),
        );
    }
  
   
  }

  Future<Map<bool, String>> createUser() async {
    try {
      UserCredential? userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
              email: _emailController.text, password: _passwordController.text);
      
      final uid = userCredential.user!.uid
      
      var data = {
        "userId": uid,
        "clientName": _firstNameController.text.toString(),
        "email": _emailController.text.toString(),
      };

      Response response =
          await Dio().post(createAccountEndpoint, data: jsonEncode(data));

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        
        return {true : "Your account was created successfully!"};
        
      } 
      return {false : "Error!"};
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return {false : "${e.code}"};
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      print("Create Account ERROR ->  ${e.message}");
      return {false : e.message};
    }
  }

Happy Coding

I've tried that code but seems to have the same error, I can't understand why

Can you please try removing the showDialog() and Navigator.pop() call in the above code?

Nope, same error xD

The problem is that you are navigating away from the current page before calling createUserData, which results in the following lines in createUserData throwing the error:
displayNotification(context, "Your account was created successfully!");

// Or alternatively

displayNotification(context, "Error!");

When you reference context in a State, the widget that that state is attached to must still exist. This will not be the case when you navigate away from the page and Flutter starts cleaning up the widgets. You will end up trying to get the context of an orphaned widget state which will at best result in undefined behavior and at worst result in an error.
The proposed solution in another answer is to pass context as a parameter. This will indeed allow you to get a valid context instance, but the problem will remain that you are using a context for a widget that no longer exists. It's just that, in this case, you will end up with a warning instead of an error if the widget has been removed from the widget tree but hasn't yet been fully cleaned up.
The solution is to simply rearrange the order in which you call things in register:
await createUserData(userCredential.user!.uid);

// Pull the Navigator.push out of the createUserData function so you don't
// end up pulling double duty
Navigator.pushReplacement(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginOrRegister()),
);

// Don't forget to change the signature of createUserData to return a Future
Future<void> createUserData(String uid) async ...

